# imageStore to RGB texture?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, compute-shader

**Is it possible in OpenGL 4.3 use `imageLoad` and `imageStore` ond GL_RGB textures?**

The supported formats listed in `glBindImageTexture​` only seem to support 1, 2 and 4 channel textures...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. Or at least, not generally.

Exactly one RGB format is supported: `r11f_g11f_b10f`. Also, the `rgb10_a2` and `rgb10_a2ui` are almost RGB.

But as far as general RGB formats are concerned? No. It should also be noted that the general RGB formats are also not [required formats for render targets](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Texture_and_Renderbuffer).

Comment: I wasn't aware that RGB support is also not very good for rendering to... thanks for pointing that out.